# How come this test fails?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm new to unit testing with jest & enzyme.

I want to test if the component has a class name 'comment-box' or not.

In the component I conduct a unit test, I do have a div with class name 'comment-box'.

But, when I run a test, it fails.

Probably, Im making an easy mistake since Im new to jest & enzyme.

Could anyone please help me to find out the problem?
Thanks!

## Log in my test runner.

```
 FAIL  src/__tests__/components/CommentBox.test.js
  ● CommentBox › has the right class

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      true
    Received:
      false
```

## CommentBox.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CommentBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="comment-box">
                <textarea></textarea>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

## CommentBox.test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

import CommentBox from '../../components/CommentBox';
jest.unmock('../../components/CommentBox');


describe('CommentBox', () => {

    it('has the correct class', () => {

        const component = shallow(<CommentBox />);

        expect(component.find('div').hasClass('comment-box')).toBe(true);

        // I tried this one as well.
        // expect(component.find('div').first().hasClass('comment-box')).toBe(true);


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<div className="comment-box">
```

Comment: No problem. `class` and `for` are common jsx gotchas.